# I want to display the percent with 2 numbers afer. for example 12.23

Tags: sql

what i already did is this, but it gives me in return a number for example 12.2536 when in fact i want 12.25

```
select njesia_adm ,
       v2003,
       t_2003,
       (cast ( v2003 as decimal) )/ cast( t_2003 as decimal )* 100  as decimal
```

from vote where `qarku='X'`

Comment: Does postgresql have a round function?

Comment: The link in the answer suggests otherwise.

Comment: tried using "to_char({ourvalue}, '999.99')" ?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the "round(v numeric, s int)" function.

> round to s decimal places

See [PostgreSQL Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE)

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this is to use that `cast()` function, but to cast the value *after* the division:

```
select njesia_adm,
       v2003,
       t_2003,
       (cast( v2003 * 100.0 / t_2003 as decimal(5, 2)) as val
```

Because this changes the type of the column, applications also understand that there are only two decimal places.  Hence, you won't see a result such as 12.2300, because the application wants to show 4 decimal places.

Note:  This should work in all databases, because `decimal()` is an ANSI standard data type and `cast()` is an ANSI standard function.